# KATE keeps forgetting I have the shell plug-in enabled

Tags: kde, 9.10, kate

I'm using Kubuntu (Karmic) and KATE is my favorite editor. I don't enable many plug-ins, but I really like the inline shell.

The problem is, across re-starts, KATE seems to forget that I enabled this plug-in. I've checked across all sessions and the behavior is the same.

Is there some easy way to fix this?

Comment: Have you checked if this is solved in lucid?

Comment: Might be related to https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=222014 - in any case, I have the same problem on Gentoo so it definitely seems to be a Kate bug, not anything specific to Kubuntu.

Comment: Yes..this occurs in lucid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug with *Kate*. But if you disable the session auto save, it loads the plugins. You can do this by changing the Application Startup Behavior to Start new session. Application Startup Behaviors can be changed from *Settings > Configure Kate > Sessions*. This is not a fix, just a walk-around.